# Implemention of Nested Tunnels in Wireguard

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, wireguard

I am currently working on a project that requires me to create nested Wireguard Tunnels. That is; I need to create a Wiregaurd tunnel between my client and Server, then create another tunnel between server and a gate. Then I forward all packages coming from the client to my server and all packages entering the server to go out through the gate. I have successfully setup the tunnels - between the client-server, and the other tunnel between server-gate. 
I am currently having issues forwarding all packages entering to pass through the gate. 
Attached here is wg0.conf of my server 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtOar.png)

I have ran the following commands and still I cant get it working

```
echo "1 middleman" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table middleman

ip rule add from <IP of the Client> lookup middleman

 wg set gate0 peer < publickey of the gate > allowed-ips 0.0.0.0/0
```

When I run

```
traceroute 4.2.2.2
```

I still can't see the traffic passing through the gate. Any help on this issue will be grately appreciated.

Comment: Your description doesn't sound like "nested tunnels" at all; it's more like "chained" tunnels.

Comment: @grawity what's the difference ??.

Comment: Nested: One tunnel's Wireguard-encrypted packets are sent inside another tunnel without decryption (producing two layers of encryption). Chained: One tunnel's packets are received, _decrypted,_ and then sent through another tunnel (replacing the old layer with the new one).

Comment: The first one Nested is what I want to achieve

Comment: @grawity Any ideas on how to go about this or how to go about chained ??

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your server wireguard config (the middle box)

```
[Interface]
Address = X.X.X.X/24 # IPV4 CIDR 
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE # Add forwarding when VPN is started
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; ip6tables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE # Remove forwarding when VPN is shutdown
```

reeplace the eth0 interface with your new vpn virtual nic. Typically utun1

You also need to enable packet forwarding in the kernel:

```
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1" > /etc/sysctl.d/wg.conf
sysctl --system
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).